# Почему на радио "шоу"?

Tags: заимствования

На радио на всех каналах звучит с утра до вечера "шоу". Если я правильно помню, "шоу" с английского - это показ. Что по радио можно показать? Выходит, что русские радийщики не знают английского? Тогда зачем они, неграмотные, вставляют слова из языка, которого не знают?

Answer (score 2):

"Шоу" — от англ. **to show** — показывать. Но даже в английском show, насколько я помню — это еще и "представление". Русский язык заимствовал и это значение. А представление может быть и по радио.